# How to plot a subgraph in igraph from a members list

Tags: python, igraph

I have a list of vertex names from a community like this:

```
members = [5735112, 5688612, 2270492, 5735148, 5442132]
```

then I need to plot the subgraph formed by the members of the list (I know they are an orbit).

I wrote this code for that:

```
subgraph_vs = g.vs.select(m for m, k in enumerate(members))

subgraph = g.subgraph(subgraph_vs)

plot(subgraph)
```

But I got this:

[image]

and should be some like this (only the blue orbit):

[image]

Only two members from the list are aggregated to the subgraph. The red ones are other vertexes that don't belong to the community.

So, I found that the problem is because the list comprehension don't return the vertex IDs to build the graph object. I mean, I need that the list comprehension returns the members IDs from the whole graph that corresponds to the members name of my list, but I don't know how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As sometimes happens, solution is trivial. Is just change the list comprehension:

```
subgraph_vs = (g.vs(name=m)[0].index for m in members)
```

And we got this:

[image]